# Is it possible to find out the version/edition of a Windows 7 installation by looking at files on the hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, version

Is it possible to find out what version of Windows 7 I have installed (for example Home Premium 64-bit) by looking at the files on the disk?

The disk I have is a MBR installed Windows 7 copied to a GPT formatted disk, and the bootloader is kind of out of order, so I can't verify.

Also, for whatever reason I have not been able to open the registry on the disk, so a method that does not need it is preferred.

Is the version string stored in any file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in the `%SystemRoot%`. There should be an .xml file with the name of the installed edition (eg. `HomePremium.xml`). For the architecture, the easiest is to check for the presence of the `SysWOW64` folder.

Comment: There are two, starter and ultimate, what next?

Answer (score 2):

To find the installed edition and licence type (retail/OEM), you can check the licence agreement, which is found at `X:\Windows\System32\license.rtf` (replace "X:" with the drive letter assigned to the Windows partition).

To find the architecture (64-bit vs. 32-bit), there are some files and folders you can check for the presence of:

- `X:\Program Files (x86)`
- `X:\Windows\SysWOW64`
- anything with "64" in the file name in `X:\Windows\inf` (that's where Windows keeps driver setup files, and a 32-bit system is not going to have 64-bit drivers)

Those files/folders only exist on a 64-bit Windows installation.

Comment: This works pretty nice!